statistical test of cell type proportions in clusters
I have a compostion dataframe which contains spotwise compositons of cell types and their cluster informations. I am required to compare the mean abundance of cell types in each cluster with other clusters. Which test should I use and how should I do it in python/R.
my dataframe looks like the following
a, b, c, d are the cell types (columns) and s1, s2 .. are spots (rownames) and one extra column clusters,which range form 1-12.
a little explanation of the test would be helpfull too.
I have tried asking this on academia, stackoverflow and now here. I hope to get some help here.
thanking you in anticipation.
